# python selenium don't find element

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to automate a process using python and the selenium library.

The item I need to click on is:
"In charge LIFE - Individual-risk recruitment".

This is the entire hierarchical structure of the HTML starting with the table id

```
<table id="contentArea" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" xpath="1">
<tbody>
   <tr>
      <td class="leftNavBg" style="width: 150px">
         <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="leftNav" statusfield="ctl00_mb_menu1_status">
<tbody>
   <tr></tr>
   <tr class="leftNavBg3" style="DISPLAY: block"></tr>
   <tr style="DISPLAY: block"></tr>
   <tr class="leftNavBg1" style="DISPLAY: block"></tr>
   <tr style="DISPLAY: block"></tr>
   <tr class="leftNavBg1" style="DISPLAY: block"></tr>
   <tr style="DISPLAY: block"></tr>
   <tr class="leftNavBg1" style="DISPLAY: block"></tr>
   <tr style="DISPLAY: block"></tr>
   <tr style="DISPLAY: block"></tr>
   <tr class="leftNavBg3" style="DISPLAY: block"></tr>
   <tr style="DISPLAY: block"></tr>
   <tr class="leftNavBg1" style="DISPLAY: block"></tr>
   <tr style="DISPLAY: block" childnum="6"></tr>
   <tr class="leftNavBg2" liv="2" style="DISPLAY: none"></tr>
   <tr style="DISPLAY: none" liv="2"></tr>
   <tr class="leftNavBg2" liv="2" style="DISPLAY: none"></tr>
   <tr style="DISPLAY: none" liv="2"></tr>
   <tr class="leftNavBg2" liv="2" style="DISPLAY: none"></tr>
   <tr style="DISPLAY: none" liv="2"></tr>
   <tr class="leftNavBg1" style="DISPLAY: block"></tr>
   <tr style="DISPLAY: block"></tr>
   <tr style="DISPLAY: block"></tr>
   <tr class="leftNavBg3" style="DISPLAY: block"></tr>
   <tr style="DISPLAY: block"></tr>
   <tr class="leftNavBg1" style="DISPLAY: block">
      <td></td>
      <td valign="top"></td>
      <td colspan="3" class="navText" align="left" style="width:133px;">
         <a class="navText" href="#" onclick="switch_menu(this, 6, 2);return false;">
         In charge LIFE - Individual-risk recruitment.
         </a>
      </td>
   </tr>
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Thank you all.

I try this:

```
try:
    element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//table[@id='contentArea']//table[@id='leftNav']//tr[@class='leftNavBg1']//td[contains(@class, 'navText') and contains(text(), 'In charge LIFE - Individual-risk recruitment')]")
    print("Element found:", element)
except NoSuchElementException:
    print("Element not found")
```

Comment: It's not the `<td>` that contains the text.  It's the `<a>` link within.  Can't you just search all of the `<a>` tags?

Answer (score 0):

To locate the element with text as *`In charge LIFE - Individual-risk recruitment`* you can use the following [locator strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//table[@id='contentArea']//table[@id='leftNav']//tr[@class='leftNavBg1']//td[@class='navText']/a[contains(., 'In charge LIFE - Individual-risk recruitment')]")
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  ```

---

Ideally to locate a ***visible*** element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*visibility_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50474905/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategy*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//table[@id='contentArea']//table[@id='leftNav']//tr[@class='leftNavBg1']//td[@class='navText']/a[contains(., 'In charge LIFE - Individual-risk recruitment')]")))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

To click on a **clickable** element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following solution:

- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//table[@id='contentArea']//table[@id='leftNav']//tr[@class='leftNavBg1']//td[@class='navText']/a[contains(., 'In charge LIFE - Individual-risk recruitment')]"))).click()
  ```

Comment: Even with the code you suggested, I can't get the element to click.

'''WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//table[@id='contentArea']//table[@id='leftNav']//tr[@class='leftNavBg1']//td[@class='navText']/a[contains(., 'In charge LIFE - Individual-risk recruitment')]"))).click()'''